# Validation loss curve is flat and training loss curve is higher than validation error curve

Tags: tensorflow, model

I'm building a LSTM model for prediction senario. My dataset has around 248000 piece of data and I use 24000 (around 10%) as validation set, others are training set. My model learning curve is the following:
[learning curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98F8B.png)

The validation error is always 0.00002 from scratch, and the training error decreased to 0.013533 at epoch 20.

I've read this carefully: https://machinelearningmastery.com/learning-curves-for-diagnosing-machine-learning-model-performance/

Is my validation set is unrepresentative? Is the solution to use larger validation set?

Comment: what about learning curves? would be helpful if you attach an image for that as well. It's difficult to judge a model purely based on error curves.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I think learning curve is the plot that shows error curve versus different epochs or training sizes. So what I uploaded is the learning curve. What do you mean by learning curve?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that, first, your underlying concept is very simple which leads to extremely low validation error early on. Second, your data augmentation makes it harder to learn, which yields higher training error.

Yet, I would still run a couple of experiments in your case. First: divide data as 10/90 instead of 90/10 and see how does your validation error changes then - hopefully, you would see some sort of a curve between (now shorter and harder) epochs. Second, I would run validation before training (or after an epoch of 1 batch) to produce a random result.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try.